# step by step process for the installation of MapR onto 20 node cluster

Tags: hadoop, mapr

I want to know the step by step process for the installation of MapR onto 20 node cluster and I also want to have an edge node. I have not installed any hadoop distribution using Edge node. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at the [MapR install documentation](http://maprdocs.mapr.com/home/AdvancedInstallation/InstallationGuide.html). 
They also have an easy to use [UI installer](http://maprdocs.mapr.com/home/AdvancedInstallation/c_get_started_install.html).